# WebView Not Load Automatically

Tags: android, xml, android-webview

I'm trying to build my FIRST app, it just. Launch -> splashscreen -> display web page automatically (fullscreen / no button trigger). But, after splashscreen, it just blank. I guess something wrong on `Intent` part in MainActivity.java, and `intent-filter` in AndroidManifest.xml. But I don't know to fix this yet.
This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.splashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

SplashScreen.java

```
package com.myapp.splashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 3 * 1000;// 3 seconds

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                SplashScreen.this.finish();

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.splashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.id.webView1);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

splashscreen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.splashscreen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want you the order to be SplashActivity -> WebViewActivity

Change in SplashActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
```

to

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    WebViewActivity.class);
```

This will tell you application that it should start the WebViewActivity instead of the MainActivity

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the WebViewActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: thx.. i try add this code, no changes..problem exist:
 <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

Comment: First, I'd delete the MainActivity. Why do you want it? it doesn't do anything... Start the WebViewActivity directly from the Splash

Comment: Second, try to set the WebViewActivity as the launcher activity, so you can discard problems in it, and be sure that it works fine